Can energy interact with the environment in General Relativity?
I've always heard in popular media that General Relativity and the Einstein's Field Equations are discribed as the following:
$$
\text{"Energy tells the space-time how to curve and curvature tells energy how to move"}
$$
But, when you model a system in GR you asume it to be like an "input" for the equations, disconnected from the physics. My questions is, could you model dynamic input situations that describes how a planet, for example, interacts with the enviroment, as well as being perturbed by it?
For example, modelling the planet as a Dirac Delta, in a similar to Electrodynamics and the retarded potentials:
$$
\Box \phi = \rho(\mathbf r, t)/\varepsilon_0 \\ \; \\
\Box \mathbf A = \mu_0 \mathbf J
$$
where:
$$
\rho(\mathbf r, t) = q \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0(t))
$$
but taking into account that $\mathbf r_0(t)$ is also influenced by the equations of motion (and do not only serves as an input).
This would be done by knowing that:
$$
T_{00} = c^2 \rho(\mathbf r, t)
$$
$$
\rho(\mathbf r, t) = \varepsilon \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf r - \mathbf r_0(t))
$$
but the field at $\mathbf r = \mathbf r_0$ is badly defined. It is possible to do this? Are there any papers written on this topic?

Einstein's Field Equations (EFE) actually also include the equations of motion of a particle within a curved space. This occurs because the Bianchi-identities require that the covariant divergence of the energy-momentum stress tensor should be zero. As a consequence the distribution and motion of matter, in particular a particle cannot be arbitrarily given, both have to be computed together with the gravitational field (the metric)  under some reasonable initial conditions.
This is different to the Maxwell equations, where matter distribution and motion of matter can be chosen arbitrarily.
When it comes to a single point particle, the question might be if this particle moves under the effect of his own created curvature. It is impossible because it would contradict energy conservation.
On the other hand the motion of a single point particle in curved space can be very well predicted (based on the EOMs), without any other forces it would move on geodesics. A priori it would also create curvature (based on the EFEs) under whose effect other particles can move.
EDIT:
Taking Lukas Nullmeiers remark into account, the spacetime around the point-particle can be described as Ricci-flat -- i.e. $R_{\mu\nu}=0$ -- and due to isotropy of space and the Birkhoff theorem we can conclude that the metric around the point-particle is Schwarzschild which disposes of an event-horizon with a singularity in the center -- in other words a black hole. Therefore, it is not a good choice to work with delta-distributions as source of matter in non-linear(!) General Relativity in difference to Maxwell theory. In the latter the superposition principle is valid which allows to work with Greens-functions.
END EDIT
This is what we know from classical physics.
However, if a perfect point particle is considered -- normally the delta function $\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{r})$ is considered only as an idealisation for simplification in classical physics -- that would be equivalent of the interaction of an elementary particle with the gravitational field. This is a problem of Quantum gravitation, a theory which up to date is incomplete. Therefore an definite answer cannot be given.

A difference between general relativity and Maxwells theory concerning delta functions is that general relativity is not linear. Therefore, a function of the form $\sum_i \delta(x-x_i)$ cannot always be approximated by a smooth function. E.g., perfectly localized classical particles would create black holes. Whereas, a smooth dust $\rho(x)$ would not.

And for example, what a about a two-planets system placed in space-time? If I set the Stress-Energy tensor to contain the information those planets, would they remain static, or will they interac with each other and give rise to a dynamic space-time?

There are different ways to do this. The easiest case is that matter is given by classical fields on spacetime. The action of general relativity in the absence of matter or radiation is given by
\begin{align}
S = \int_{\mathcal M} d^4 x \sqrt{-g}  \frac{1}{2\varkappa} (R-2\Lambda) \,.
\end{align}
In order to describe the interplay with matter the action must be supplemented by the corresponding matter Lagrangian
\begin{align}
S = \int_{\mathcal M} d^4 x \sqrt{-g} \left[ \frac{1}{2\varkappa} (R-2\Lambda) + \mathcal L_{M}\right]\,,
\end{align}
For simplicity let's consider a scalar field $\phi:\mathcal M \to \mathbb R$, with the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian given by
\begin{align}
\mathcal L_M = \frac{1}{2} g^{\alpha \beta} (\partial_\alpha \phi) (\partial_\beta \phi) -\frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2\,.
\end{align}
The variation of $S$ with respect to the metric $g$ and the scalar field $\phi$ yields the Einstein field equations
\begin{align}
R_{\mu\nu}- \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu} R + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \varkappa T_{\mu\nu}\,,
\end{align}
on the one hand and the Klein-Gordon equation in curved space time
$$
g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_nu \nabla_\mu \phi - m^2 \phi = 0\,.
$$
The energy momentum tensor is given by
$$
T_{\mu \nu} = - \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\partial [\sqrt{-g} \mathcal L_M]}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}}
=-(\partial_\alpha \phi) (\partial_\beta \phi) + g_{\mu\nu} \frac{1}{2} g^{\alpha \beta} (\partial_\alpha \phi) (\partial_\beta \phi)- g_{\mu\nu} \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2
$$
In the Einstein field equation, matter tells spacetime how to curve. In the Klein-Gordon equation spacetime tells matter how to move.

(+1) Could you elaborate whether taking $T_{\mu\nu}$ from the Dirac/KG equation and inputing that "waveform" into GR is a valid procedure? I mean whether the Dirac/Klein-Gordon $T_{\mu\nu}$ is a real, physical entity that curves space exactly like the shape of its waveform?

It depends on whether there is physical stuff out there that described (approximately) by a classical Dirac/KG-field. A physical example would be given by the electromagnetic field $A_\mu$. The question concerning the Dirac field is more difficult. Since the quantum-field is usually a fermionic field there are no coherent states where the quantum field would correspond to a classical Dirac field. Therefore, the classical Dirac field does not provide an approximation of the quantum field. In any case, the shape of space time does not correspond directly to the shape of the field $\phi$.
